# MDX calculated members in subquery

Tags: ssas, mdx, members

As query calculated members are not allowed in subselects (SSAS v12), is there any solution to still use them? A session calculated member is not an option, as the same session is shared by multiple callers (which define new calc. members, so a negative interference could occur).
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the MDX query that you have tried along with the expected outcome?

Comment: No, you cannot use calculated measures in subqueries.